# Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist, casting

I'm working on a music store that allows you to buy songs using an MVC framework consisting of Servlets, JSPs and JavaBeans. I have a ControllerServlet that dispatches requests to relevant JSP views based on the action value for the forms in the JSPs. There is another class in the same package called CartBean that serves as a model for 2 array lists containing information about songs and albums (each calling 2 other different JavaBeans called SongBean and AlbumBean). The following is the start of the servlet where the 3 types of beans are declared as global variables, so that they are exposed to the whole class, not just within doGet and doPost.

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class ControllerServlet
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/search", displayName="ControllerServlet")
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    // make the SongBean and AlbumBean global variables so the parsed data is available
    // to whole class (not just doGet) as long as class exists
    public ArrayList<SongBean> songs = new ArrayList<SongBean>();
    public ArrayList<AlbumBean> albums = new ArrayList<AlbumBean>();
    public CartBean cart = new CartBean();
```

Within doPost method, I have the following where if the user tries to add something to a shopping cart, he is supposed to be able to do so when he selects some checkboxes in the search results JSP view that is returned from a doGet.

```
                } else if (action.equals("add")) {

                    String selected[] = request.getParameterValues("checkbox-anything-songs"); 

                    // iterate through the songs selected in results.jsp for matching songs in order to add to cart
                    for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("You selected song with songID: " + selected[i]);

                        // iterate through SongBeans in global variable, songs
                        for (SongBean song : songs) {
                            // selected song is added to cart using songID to match with SongBean's songID & break out of for loop
                            if (song.getSongID().matches(selected[i])) {
                                cart.addSong(song);
                                break;
                            }
                        }   

                    } 
                    ArrayList<SongBean> songsInCart = cart.getSongs();
                    System.out.println("You added " + selected.length + " songs to your cart and have a total of " + cart.getSongs().size() + " songs in your cart now!");
                    System.out.println("Songs in cart now: " + songsInCart);

                    request.setAttribute("songsCart", songsInCart);
                    RequestDispatcher requestdispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/cart.jsp");   
                    requestdispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

I'm trying to bring the object for either cart or songsInCart over to the cart.jsp view, so that I can show the saved data within it. I know the right data is saved in the object as I see in the console printing and know that it is saving the right data in it. Problem is, when I try to show it in the cart.jsp view after dispatching the request to there and using getAttribute to get the songsCart object, it keeps giving me the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /cart.jsp at line 182

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /cart.jsp at line 182

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /cart.jsp at line 182

179:    
180:    <!-- Message about whether the shopping cart is empty or not -->
181:    <c:choose>
182:        <c:when test="<%= songbean.size() == 0 && albumbean.size() == 0 %>">
183:            <h2><small>Your shopping cart is empty.</small></h2>
184:        </c:when>
185:        <c:when test="<%= songbean.size() >= 1 || albumbean.size() >= 1 %>">
```

I suspect that it has something to do with the code at the top of the cart.jsp, which is the following and I get a warning message "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList" for the line: "ArrayList songbean = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("songsCart");":

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="edu.unsw.comp9321.*, java.util.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%
    // initialize session

    // get the beans from importing edu.unsw.comp9321.*
    CartBean cartBean;
    SongBean songBean;
    AlbumBean albumBean;

    // check the session status to see if session has been initialized and shopping cart activated
    if (session.getAttribute("shopping") == null) {
        cartBean = new CartBean();
        songBean = new SongBean();
        albumBean = new AlbumBean();
        session.setAttribute("shopping", cartBean);
        session.setAttribute("songBean", songBean);
        session.setAttribute("albumBean", albumBean);
        System.out.println("cart.jsp: Creating New Session.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("cart.jsp: Already In Session.");
    }

    cartBean = (CartBean) session.getAttribute("shopping");

    // get SongBeans and AlbumBeans so can fetch CartBean attributes from them
    ArrayList<SongBean> songbean = (ArrayList<SongBean>) session.getAttribute("songsCart");

    ArrayList<AlbumBean> albumbean = cartBean.getAlbums();
%>
```

I dunno what is wrong and I suspect it is something to do with the songsCart object not being properly converted into an ArrayList containing all the songs. Either that or it has something to do with the c tags, or not doing the getAttributes correctly. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: *" An exception occurred"* Which one is it? Go find it in server log if you don't see it in error page. That exception represents the entire answer at its own.

Comment: I can't find the log...

Comment: Then you have another problem to solve first.

Comment: Is it catalina.out in the logs folder in the tomcat apache directory? It does not shows today's logs

Comment: The location of the logfile depends on how the server is configured and how it is started. If it's e.g. an unmodified Tomcat instance integrated in Eclipse and executed via Eclipse's *Servers* view, then the log is in Eclipse's very own *Console* view.

Comment: ArrayList<SongBean> songbean = request.getSession().getAttribute("songsCart");  ===> When I have this in the JSP file, I keep getting error for that line saying that "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to ArrayList<SongBean>". I have set the attribute in my servlet, I just need to be able to convert the object to ArrayList and my problem will be solved I think.

Comment: Your question in its current form already contains the correct line for that.